Как мне указать {id} в requestMatchers?
Вот код:
@Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers("/", "/files/[0-9]+", "/box/[0-9]+", "/registration", "/hello")
                        .permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .formLogin(form -> form.loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                        .successHandler(new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler()).permitAll()
                        .defaultSuccessUrl("/").permitAll())
                .logout(logout -> logout.logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll())
                .build();
    }

"/files/[0-9]+", "/box/[0-9]+" не работают.
Пробовал "/files/**", "/box/*" и т. д. — не подходит, т. к. есть и другие пути от /box/. К примеру, /box/create и т. д.

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Ну как мне записать, все понятно
